# Getting an error for a command that is working in a previous function

Tags: lua

The code runs the activateVacuum command with no problems, but when activateVacuum(1) is called, it says that there is the error:
One of the function's argument type is not correct. (sim.setObjectParent)
stack traceback: [C]: in function 'setObjectParent' [string "CHILD SCRIPT LBR_iiwa_7_R800"]:52: in function 'activateVacuum1' [string "CHILD SCRIPT LBR_iiwa_7_R800"]:125: in main chunk

```
activateVacuum=function()
    sim.setIntegerSignal('Chevy_Charger',Chevy_Charger)
    object_h = sim.getIntegerSignal('Chevy_Charger')
    connector = sim.getObjectHandle('BaxterGripper_attachPoint')
    sim.setObjectParent(object_h,connector,true)
    sim.setIntegerSignal('BaxterGripper_close',1)
    -- this the line that converts the charger into a dynamic object
    sim.setObjectInt32Parameter(Chevy_Charger,3003,1)
    has_grabed_an_object = true
end 

deactivateVacuum=function()

if has_grabed_an_object then
    sim.setIntegerSignal('BaxterGripper_close',0)
    sim.setObjectParent(object_h,connector,true)
    -- this the line that converts it to static
    sim.setObjectInt32Parameter(Chevy_Charger,3003,0)
    has_grabed_object=false
else
    sim.setStringSignal('error','no object detected')
end
end

activateVacuum1=function()
    sim.setIntegerSignal('base_link_responsable2',Tesla_Charger)
    object_h = sim.getIntegerSignal('Tesla_Charger')
    connector = sim.getObjectHandle('BaxterGripper_attachPoint')
    sim.setObjectParent(object_h,connector,true)
    sim.setIntegerSignal('BaxterGripper_close',1)
    sim.setObjectInt32Parameter(Tesla_Charger,3003,1)
    has_grabed_an_object = true
end 
deactivateVacuum1=function()

if has_grabed_an_object then
    sim.setIntegerSignal('BaxterGripper_close',0)
    sim.setObjectParent(object_h,connector,false)
    sim.setObjectInt32Parameter(Tesla_Charger,3003,0)
    has_grabed_object=false
else
    sim.setStringSignal('error','no object detected')
end
end
enter code here
```